# wordpress error after 3.6 update Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'cookie' of undefined

Tags: wordpress, cookies, jquery-cookie

i have problem with my wordpress page after update to ver 3.6. I didn't make any changes in code but site is not working now, showing the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'cookie' of undefined
```

code:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/themes/ewe/style.css" type="text/css">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" id="superstyle-css" href="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/themes/ewe/js/supersized.core.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js?ver=3.6">    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.cookie.js?ver=3.6"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.9.js?ver=3.6"></script>
      <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.ewerosinska.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
      <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"> 
      <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.6">
<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ewerosinska.com/wp-content/themes/ewe/js/supersized.3.2.7.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     if($.cookie('has_seen_palms')!='1'){
```

the error appears in the last line, my website adress is [ewerosinska.com](http://www.ewerosinska.com/)
Does anyone know hot to fix that?
Thanks a lot
Evelyn

Comment: From what version did you update? Try with `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, note the **`$`**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object \[object Object\] is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795817/wordpress-jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-object-is-n)